# nginx redirect twice from https to http

Tags: nginx, https

i have 2 servers, one has ssl and i config it like this,

in the server with SSL certification(which is https:// www.example.com):

```
location ~^/abc/.* {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com:8214/
}
```

in another server(which is http:// www.anotherExample.com):

```
server {
     listen 8214;
     server_name www.anotherExample.com;
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.anotherExample.com:8080/$1 permanent;
 }
```

and after access https:// www.example.com/abc/api/getGroup

it can't redirect to http:// www.anotherExample.com:8080/api/getGroup

Anything wrong???

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you could do to improve your configuration.

```
location ^~ /abc/ {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com:8214$uri;
    #You should have other directives set here as well.
}
```

Also, consider setting up an `upstream`.
Then, for your server block:

```
server{
    listen 8124;
    server_name www.anotherExample.com;
    rewrite ^/abc/(.*)$ http://www.anotherExample.com:8080/$1 permanent;
}

server{
    listen 8080;
    server_name www.anotherExample.com;

    location ^~ /api/ {
        #your_config_here
    }
}
```

The explanation:

In your first `location` block, you shouldn't have `.*` in the expression. Nginx will match this for you. Then, when you're proxying, you can explicitly tell Nginx to send the URI as well.

Next, you're sending the URI `www.anotherExample.com:8124`, which includes `/abc/`, so you want to extract everything after that.

Lastly, because you've rewritten it to point to `8080` port, you'll need to define a separate server block for this.

I don't know what you're aiming to achieve, but so much proxying and redirects isn't necessary in most cases, and might lead to poor performance. Another consideration that you should take into account is you're sending unencrypted information to anotherExample.com, which, if not on the same local network, might be a security vulnerability.